# What to use instead of await in initState() method?

Tags: flutter

I get this error

> A value of type 'Future' can't be assigned to a
> variable of type 'double'.
> because we can not use assync in initState() method.

```
class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  bool _isSwitched = false;
  double _sliderValue = 0;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    _sliderValue = _getInterval();
    super.initState();
  }
...

Future<double> _getInterval() async { ...
```

But if we will try to use await in the initState() then we'll get the message

> Rather than awaiting on asynchronous work directly inside  of
> initState, call a separate method to do this work without awaiting
> it.

How can I use _getInterval inside initState, i.e. recieve a future value from it, without awaiting it?

Comment: use `Future.then()` method then

Comment: @Rozerro did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run this code `_sliderValue = _getInterval();`, you can put it inside a seperate method

```
void myMethod() async{
   _sliderValue = await _getInterval();
}
```

And then call it inside `initState` method, like below:

```
@override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    myMethod();
  }
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch ;)

Comment: the initState method cann't be async

Comment: The initState can't be async but you can use Future into initState method

Comment: If you get your answer please upvote and approve my answer (-;

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `_getInterval` method without awaiting it and change it to instead of returning the value assign it to the `_sliderValue` at the end of the method (probably also calling `setState`)